# Trust a self signed certificate without a cer file?

Tags: java, android, flutter, https, ssl-certificate

So this mobile app I'm working on is primarily in flutter but I have some API callbacks in native Android and Swift that I would like to keep, however the thing is the actual api calls can be to custom servers. After realizing that Flutter cannot read manually installed user certificates on Android, I tried to figure out a way to do it like chrome and ask the user "Do you want to trust this certificate y/n", however I can't figure out a way to do it on Java.

On the flutter side, theres a callback part of HttpClient called badCertificateCallback, where if anywhere in the app a certificate is unsafe it will automatically refer to there no matter where the certificate is called, currently on the flutter side I have it set so that if the user trusts a certain link, it will trust that certificates information, is there something similar on Android I can do? Most of the other solutions I found wanted to either trust all certificates which isn't ideal or required the user to have a cer file somewhere.

Comment: Frame challenge: why are you self-signing in the first place? Just use certs from a trusted root authority. Did you ever see any app ask you to accept some random certificate?

Comment: I have both used self-signed and certs signed by my own CA. Unless my root certificate is not installed in the truststore, some apps do ask whether they should trust the server. Unfortunately Android is annoying to warn that someone has hacked my phone just because I added my own root certificate.

Comment: @Michael Well because users can connect to custom servers they made and host themselves, in which case I would not have access to their certs

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways that you can go:

- Either you add your self-signed certificate to your client's truststore.
- Or you use your own certificate authority to sign the server's certificate signing request (CSR) and add that certificate authority's certificate to the truststore of your client. Even here you could decide to just add the server's certificate to the truststore directly, but then why did you use the CA?
- Or you use an official certificate authority (let's encrypt, geocerts, digicert, ...) to sign the certificate. Since the official certificate authorities are already installed in your client's truststore, no additional step would be necessary.

Short answer: You will not succeed without a certificate. But it does not have to be a `.cer` file.

Since you are denying the 'no certificate check/trust all': checking certificates is the better way, even if you use a self-signed certificate. But the client needs something to check against, and that data usually is transported in certificates. You can store such a certificate in different file formats. Check this page: https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/what-are-certificate-formats-and-what-is-the-difference-between-them/